# How to dispose wizard pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a "complex" composite, which contains some widgets and listens for some events (i.e., it register itself into another element). I also implemented a dispose method in that composite, which deregister itself from the notifications and call the dispose on the composite (`super.dispose()`).

I use this widget in several places, including a page of a Wizard. However, it seems that when the wizard closes  (either with a "finish" or a "cancel"), my widget is not disposed. Indeed, the dispose method of a WizardPage is pretty simple, as it only cleans the image.

Am I missing something or I must perform an explicit dispose on my composite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your `dispose()` implementation of your "complex" composite class for cleaning up resources allocated this widget explicitly within your implementation of the wizard page `dispose()` method, but this only works for the wizard page!.

A better way seems to add a dispose listener to your composite/widget and perform cleanup steps in the `widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e)` method of the DisposeListener.